# Shift-Invariance of Dirac Comb?

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

Is a dirac comb a Linear and a shift Invariant System? I could prove the linearity, but I do not think it is shift invariant. How do do I prove it is shift variant?

Comment: A "dirac comb" is not a system. Be more precise please with what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If by dirac comb you mean a system with $y(t) = \sum_kx(t-kT)$ equation:
$$
y(t) = \sum_kx(t-kT) = \sum_kx(t)\ast \delta(t-kT) = x(t) \ast \underbrace{\sum_k\delta(t-kT)}_{h(t)}
$$
Therefore $h(t)$ is impluse response of the system and the system is Linear Time Invariant (LTI).

Comment: Okay, by Dirac delta function, I meant sampling function. I am having to prove that the sampling function is linear but NOT shift-invariant.

Comment: Well obviously, if a system can be described by a impulse response, it is linear time invariant because that is a necessary and sufficient condition for this.
Still the question is totally confuse to me. 
And sorry, "sampling function" is not a well defined term either!

Comment: Also in the OP you did not say "Dirac delta function", but "Dirac comb", which is something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you´re refering to this system, I can assure that it´s not time invariant since an input x(t-t0) doesnt lead to an output y(t-t0). In fact Theres no way to express the transfer function of this system, since this is a convolution in frequency domain (or s-domain).

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? The question was not about the "system" being time invariant and I struggle to see where does the s-domain come into play here (?)

Comment: As far as I’ve seen in the literature, Time-invariance property does make sense only for systems, not signals, you can’t say a signal is time- invariant or non time-inv (correct me if I’m wrong) that’s why I was proposing a system because it’s a common system (sampling function).  Since “transfer functions” it’s a representation only for linear time-invariant system, there’s no way to represent a non time-inv system as a transfer function, I was just giving some extra point to reaffirm this system wasn’t time-invariant. But you can see that by definition, The system isn’t time invariant.